# How do i change a Member Nickname in DSharpPlus

Tags: c#, .net, discord

How do i change a member nickname in D#+ SlashCommands?

I Tried `context.Member.Nickname = "NICKNAME_HERE"` but it says "Property or indexer 'DiscordMember.Nickname' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found that you can do
`await context.Member.ModifyAsync(x => x.Nickname = "Test")`

Basically `context` is the class `InteractionContext` or `CommandContext` in a command function
and `Member` is the current user who is using the command
and `ModifyAsync` will make a change to the user properties and we await it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).